# $_post при нажатии на ссылку

Tags: php, javascript, html

Добрый день, дорогие друзья, подскажите как реализовать такую штуку:
есть поле для ввода текста. туда пишем слово, а дальше жмем на **ссылку** на странице и срабатывает метод пост из формы? Знаю, что такое можно сделать для кнопки при помощи id. А вот как сделать чтобы ссылка запускала этот же процесс пока не знаю. Подскажите, кто в курсе?

Answer (score 3):

В общем случае нужно перехватить событие клика на ссылку и выполнить своё действие, в данном случае - отправить форму.
Но на практике никогда так не делайте, если на странице есть ссылка, она должна иметь нормальный URL, например, что бы её можно было открыть на новой странице.

html

```
<form method="post" id="form1">
<input type="text" value="" />
<a href="#" id="form_submit">Submit</a>
</form>
```

js

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    document.getElementById('form_submit').onclick = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById('form1').submit();
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" value="" />
<a href="#" id="form_submit">Submit</a>
</form>

$(function () {
    $('#form_submit').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    });
});
```